# WPF Multiple CombinedGeometry

Tags: wpf, binding, geometry

I wish to bind a collection of viewmodels with X,Y,Radius properties to a CombinedGeometry of circles using Union. However it seems that CombinedGeometry only supports 2 Geometries.

Is there anyway around this limitation?

Example of what I'm aiming for

```
<Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="#CCCCFF">
  <Path.Data>
    <CombinedGeometry GeometryCombineMode="Union" ItemsSource="{Binding Circles}">
      <CombinedGeometry.Template>
        <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="{Binding Radius}" RadiusY="{Binding Radius}" CenterX="{Binding X}" CenterY="{Binding Y}"/>
      </CombinedGeometry.Template>
    </CombinedGeometry>
  </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

It is indeed possible to have CombinedGeometries within CombinedGeometry as seen below. However, I don't know how to set it up so that it is easily bindable.

```
   <Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="#CCCCFF">
        <Path.Data>

        <!-- Combines two geometries using the union combine mode. -->
        <CombinedGeometry GeometryCombineMode="Union">
            <CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                <CombinedGeometry GeometryCombineMode="Union">
                    <CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                        <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="50" RadiusY="50" Center="200,200" />
                    </CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                    <CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                        <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="50" RadiusY="50" Center="125,200" />
                    </CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                </CombinedGeometry>
            </CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
            <CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                <CombinedGeometry GeometryCombineMode="Union">
                    <CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                        <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="50" RadiusY="50" Center="100,100" />
                    </CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                    <CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                        <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="50" RadiusY="50" Center="150,120" />
                    </CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                </CombinedGeometry>
            </CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
        </CombinedGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for [GeometryGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.geometrygroup.aspx) ?

MSDN Code Sample :

```
<Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="#CCCCFF">     
  <Path.Data>
    <!-- Creates a composite shape from three geometries. -->
    <GeometryGroup FillRule="EvenOdd">
      <LineGeometry StartPoint="10,10" EndPoint="50,30" />
      <EllipseGeometry Center="40,70" RadiusX="30" RadiusY="30" />          
      <RectangleGeometry Rect="30,55 100 30" />
    </GeometryGroup>      
  </Path.Data>  
</Path>
```

Comment: It is close to what I want, but lacks the union feature. I need to merge overlapping shapes so that only 1 outline exists. I have attempted using 2 sets of Geometry groups, 1 for the fill and 1 for the outline, however in some cases I need the fill to be transparent which makes this method invalid.

Comment: @Ying - Did you try the different options for the FillRule property ? Also if that fails to work - check if a CombinedGeometry can be composed of other CombinedGeometry objects.

Comment: Yes, CombinedGeometry can be composed of other CombinedGeometry objects, but I got no idea how to set it up so that I can simply bind a collection to it. See my edited question

Comment: @Ying - `<EllipseGeometry RadiusX="{Binding Path=ViewModelCollection[0].RadiusX}" ...` where ViewModelCollection is an indexer - Do you mean something like this ?

Comment: I want to be able to dynamically add and remove circles that will be unioned. Can you give me an example of how to do it with your idea?

Comment: I'm not sure if Binding will help you here.. The obvious way to do this would be to use to use DataTemplates that will render a ViewModel object as a EllipseGeometry. However this whole business of composing CombinedGeometry objects looks like will have to be done via custom code... See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593860

Answer (score 1):

This code produces the same result as the second code by the OP:

```
<Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="#CCCCFF">
    <Path.Data>
        <CombinedGeometry GeometryCombineMode="Union">
            <CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                <!-- any geometry here -->
                <GeometryGroup/>
            </CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
            <CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                <GeometryGroup FillRule="Nonzero">
                    <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="50" RadiusY="50" Center="200,200" />
                    <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="50" RadiusY="50" Center="125,200" />
                    <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="50" RadiusY="50" Center="100,100" />
                    <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="50" RadiusY="50" Center="150,120" />
                </GeometryGroup>
            </CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
        </CombinedGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

And instead of all the `<EllipseGeometry>`, you can bind to a collection via `Children="{Binding Circles}"` in `<GeometryGroup>`.

Answer (score 0):

I have kind of a similar problem and found a hepfull post here:
[How to make the border trim the child elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649875/wpf-how-to-make-the-border-trim-the-child-elements)

You could also try to create a converter that receives the collection in that binding and builds up the combined geometries as desired.
I'll do exactly that now :)

Comment: Actually my problem has been solved by `group.FillRule = FillRule.Nonzero;`